# Transfer a multidimensional arrays even elements to a one dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which is a 10 by 10 `arr[10][10]`
and i want to transfer the even numbers to another array which is one dimensional `even[50]`here is what i did:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        if (arr[0][x] % 2 == 0) {
            even[x] = arr[0][x];
        }
    }
```

Now lets assume i have `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` on `arr[0][x]`
The problem i have with it is now that the if statement works the even element for example `{6}` gets stored on `even[6]` and `even[5]`as well as the other odd numbers on the `even[]`array will have no value in them just they just have random memory numbers i want the even elements to be next to each other like

`even[0]=0, even[1]=2, even[2]=4` and so on

is there a more efficient way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 indexes

```
size_t even_index = 0;

// some looping condition
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    // Some filter test
    if (arr[0][x] % 2 == 0) {
        if (even_index >= 50) Oops_Handle_Error();
        even[even_index++] = arr[0][x];
    }
}

printf("even[] elements used:%zu\n", even_index);
```

Comment: can i do it without using indexes?

Comment: @KardoKamal Sure, use a pointer `int *e_ptr = even; ... *e_ptr++ = arr[0][x];`